# Converting XML to JSON array using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, json.net

I have the following XML that I need to convert to the JSON shown below.  I am using Newtonsoft.Json and cannot find the right combination of configuration and `json:Array` attributes to get what I need.  Are there other attributes I am missing?  Do I need to write a custom converter?

Here is my XML:

```
<Container>
  <Encounters>
    <Encounter>
      <a>a1</a>
      <b>b1</b>
    </Encounter>
    <Encounter>
      <a>a2</a>
      <b>b2</b>
    </Encounter>
  </Encounters>
</Container>
```

This is the JSON I need:

```
{
  "Container": {
    "Encounters" : [
      {
        "a": "a1",
        "b": "b1"
      },
      {
        "a": "a2",
        "b": "b2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the JSON I currently am getting:

```
{
  "Container": {
    "Encounters" : {
      "Encounter" : [
        {
          "a": "a1",
          "b": "b1"
        },
        {
          "a": "a2",
          "b": "b2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just use `json:Array='true'` to the XML tag you want to convert to Array.

Comment: If I add json:Array='true' to Encounters I get "Encounters" : [ "Encounter" : [ etc... That is not what I want.

Comment: Add `json:Array='true'` to Container tag

Comment: That change just made everything underneath an array "Container" : [ { "Encounters" : { "Encounter" : [ etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json:Array='true'` isn't going to give you the result you want in this situation.  This attribute is intended to signal that you want a particular XML element to be treated as an array when it is converted to JSON in the case that there is only one of them.  If there are multiple of a particular XML element, they will automatically be treated as an array.  So in your case, the multiple `Encounter` elements will become an array inside the single `Encounters` object.  It looks like you actually want to flatten this down one level.  Json.Net does not have a way to do this using attributes in the XML.  So there are three possible approaches I can see to solve this:

1. Manipulate the XML before converting it to JSON
2. Manipulate the JSON after converting it from XML
3. Write a custom XML-to-JSON converter to do what you want.

I think approach 2 is probably the easiest using the [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects):

```
string xml =
@"<Container>
  <Encounters>
    <Encounter>
      <a>a1</a>
      <b>b1</b>
    </Encounter>
    <Encounter>
      <a>a2</a>
      <b>b2</b>
    </Encounter>
  </Encounters>
</Container>";

// Convert XML to a JObject
JObject root = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(XElement.Parse(xml)));

// Move the array of Encounter objects up one level
JProperty encounters = ((JObject)root["Container"]).Property("Encounters");
encounters.Value = encounters.Value["Encounter"];

// Output the JSON
string json = root.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{
  "Container": {
    "Encounters": [
      {
        "a": "a1",
        "b": "b1"
      },
      {
        "a": "a2",
        "b": "b2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kk1Exr